# Where is Authorization in building applications necessary?

Tags: architecture, authorization, backend

I am building the backend of a website using Nodejs and the site is more or less a replica of https://www.complex.com/. As I start I have a checklist of the features to implement which is borrowed from this page [Backend Architecture checklist](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/have-an-idea-want-to-build-a-product-from-scratch-heres-a-checklist-of-things-you-should-go-through-in-your-backend-software-architecture/) and one of them is to enforce Authorization/Authentication. I want to understand if for such a website that will not require users to create accounts, is this applicable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to build Authentication/Authorization flows into your system if it doesn't need to manage users (but rather visitors). It's true that the article doesn't explicitly say this, it's kind of an assumed requirement for those features.

However, if you think that long term there may be a chance to add user-management into your system, you should carefully design your architecture to account for this.